# Selector for next sibling of current element

Tags: java, css-selectors, jsoup

What is the way to select next sibling using purely CSS selector syntax and not a method call?

e.g. given:

```
<div>Foo</div><whatever>bar</whatever>
```

if Element `e` represents the `div` then I need to select the `<whatever>` irrespective of if it's a `<div>` or `<p>` or whatever.

```
String selectorForNextSibling = "... ";
Element whatever = div.select(selectorForNextSibling).get(0);
```

The reason for looking for such a selector is to have a generic method that can fetch data from either a sibling or a child node.

I'm trying to parse an app's HTML where the position of `div` cannot be computed a selector. Otherwise, this would been as easy as using:

```
"div.thespecificDivID + div,div.thespecificDivID + p"
```

What I want essentially is to drop the `div.thespecificDivID` part from above selector, (e.g. if this worked : "+div, +p" )

Comment: Is this resolved? http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You can use the direct [sibling selector `element + directSibling`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/sel_element_pluss.asp) in combination with the [wildcard selector `*`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_all.asp)

*Note*: Since you are using jsoup, I include [jsoups `nextElementSibling()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#nextElementSibling--) even though you requested: "not method call".

**Example Code**

```
String html = "<div>1A</div><p>1A 1B</p><p>1A 2B</p>\r\n" + 
        "<div>2A</div><span>2A 1B</span><p>2A 2B</p>\r\n" + 
        "<div>3A</div><p>3A 1B</p>\r\n" + 
        "<p>3A 2B</p><div></div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

String eSelector = "div";

System.out.println("with e.cssSelector and \" + *\"");
// if you also need to do something with the Element e
doc.select(eSelector).forEach(e -> {
    Element whatever = doc.select(e.cssSelector() + " + *").first();
    if(whatever != null) System.out.println("\t" + whatever.toString());
});

System.out.println("with direct selector and \" + *\"");
// if you are only interested in Element whatever
doc.select(eSelector + " + * ").forEach(whatever -> {
    System.out.println("\t" + whatever.toString());
});

System.out.println("with jsoups nextElementSibling");
//use jsoup build in function
doc.select(eSelector).forEach(e -> {
    Element whatever = e.nextElementSibling();
    if(whatever != null) System.out.println("\t" + whatever.toString());
});
```

**Output**

```
with e.cssSelector and " + *"
    <p>1A 1B</p>
    <span>2A 1B</span>
    <p>3A 1B</p>
with direct selector and " + *"
    <p>1A 1B</p>
    <span>2A 1B</span>
    <p>3A 1B</p>
with jsoups nextElementSibling
    <p>1A 1B</p>
    <span>2A 1B</span>
    <p>3A 1B</p>
```